# How to use Resharper to move using statements

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

Resharper did some refactoring for me and added using statements to the top of my files. Unfortuantely it added them in the wrong place. I need them to be within some preserve comments so that they don't get wiped out by our code generation software. Currently my files look like this:

```
/******************************************************************************************
 Copyright Info at the top of every file
**************************************************************************************/

using Something.Added.By.Resharper;

namespace Some.Namespace {
using Statements.Generated.By.Our.Code.Generation.Software;

// PRESERVE:BEGIN
using Statements.ThatWont.Be.Wiped.Out.By.Generation.Software;
// PRESERVE: END
```

I need to move that upper statement down into the `PRESERVE` comments. How can I achieve this refactoring across thousands of files?

Comment: That works great for one or two files, but not the thousands that I have to deal with...

Comment: One possibility is to write a ReSharper plugin (this would most likely be a Code Cleanup action) that can do this for you.